I need to making smtp message sending faster and sending multiple messages in the span of seconds
def send_message(phone_number, carrier, message):
    recipient = phone_number + CARRIERS[carrier]
    auth = (EMAIL, PASSWORD)

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(auth[0], auth[1])

    server.sendmail(auth[0], recipient, message)

This code just sends messages.
The problem is I am calling this say 2 or 3 times in a row and there is a long lag between messages. How can I fix this? I tried threading but can not get it to work.

Can you, please, show how you tried threading?

Can you include logs that show the timing of the message processing?

Can you pipeline multiple messages?  The mail server may very well be throttling you.

Probably a Gmail anti mass mailing feature. Simply don't use Gmail for reliable automated mailings.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
